# Zombie stories compilation book with this particular short story?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, zombie-apocalypse

First story of all was about a woman, an old teacher in a post-zombie apocalypse world, who tried to teach the zombies (her old students), and lived alone in her old school.

I tried to find that book for years and i found nothing. I read it in Spanish.

Comment: Can you give us a time period in which you read it?

Comment: I read it like 2 or 3 years ago, I think on 2011 summer.

Comment: I know the story, (in English), but I don't remember the book title. I'm fairly sure it was a zombie-themed collection.  At the end of the story, her "students" have gotten loose, but instead of attacking her they take their places at their desks and wait for her to start teaching.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compilation, in English, is "[The Living Dead](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3302568-the-living-dead)", edited by John Joseph Adams, published 2008 by Night Shade Books.

The first story is "[This Year's Class Picture](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48351)" by Dan Simmons.

[image]

Comment: Your image is dead. [See here](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10694/70236)